# Relative path for Django Static Files: Template Tag or Variable

Tags: python, django

Is there any diference (in system performance, response, code quality, or whatever I shoud care) when I point a relative path with a template tag compared to the use of a variable?
Is template tag is a function? Which is faster, call a function or a variable?

Exemple:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hi.jpg" />

<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" />
```

Well, about code quality, the Django manual says to use template tag and I agree that follow the manual is "more right". But, aparently, this isn't a big deal.

Comment: Just read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18400426/1326200)

Comment: Thank you! I searched but can´t find that question/answer before... it´s enlightening